# Creating pages from data in table using href

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using PHP here for a custom page in Wordpress.

I am using data from mysql to build a table. I want the data (in this case, city names) to be "a href" and individually create a new page with the data name as URL.

So I want to click any city name in the table on this page and it will bring me to a new page with the city name as url.

Here is what I have:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="citytable"     width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>CITIES</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php        

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Cities' )     ) ); ?>">$cell</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't seem to make it work. Please help!

Comment: can you please share $result..? or i can say your query.

Comment: You are using wordpress, so take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query and http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb instead of using `mysql_...` functions

Comment: $Result returns 1 array of 38 cities.

Comment: thn please share that arrray so that i can help you to print those cities name with link.. ?

Answer (score 1):

please try below code:

long time reader first time poster. Using PHP here for a custom page in Wordpress.

I am using data from mysql to build a table. I want the data (in this case, city names) to be "a href" and individually create a new page with the data name as URL.

So I want to click any city name in the table on this page and it will bring me to a new page with the city name as url.

Here is what I have:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="citytable"     width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>CITIES</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php        

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{ ?>
<tr>
<?php
foreach($row as $cell) { ?>
    <td>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title($cell)));?>"><?php echo $cell; ?></a>
    </td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

 </tbody>
</table>
```